# Counting points on curves

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nt.number-theory, algebra

It is known (see "[Counting curves and their projections](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01202042)" ([free version](https://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/pubs/gatkar93.pdf)) by von zur Gathen, Karpinski, and Shparlinski) that the problem of finding the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points on a curve in sparse representation is $\mathsf{\# P}$ complete. Note that the degree of such curve can be exponentially large since sparse representation allows it.

But assume that the degree of a curve is not greater than some polynomial. Can we find the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points of this curve by using, say, constant iterations of Arthur-Merlin protocol?

Comment: Note that constantly many rounds of AM is the same complexity class as AM... In your question, do you mean that you have a *sparse* polynomial of bounded degree, or just a degree bound (*instead* of a sparsity bound)?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I think both questions are interesting